# What is “Oracle Access”?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays

I'm reading a paper for school and I have come across a passage that I don't understand. It says "If we allow the query to access the entries of the array through an oracle, it is possible to obtain a data structure of sublinear size".

Searching for information on what Oracle Access is has given me nothing but stuff about Oracle Databases, which is obviously not what I'm looking for. I can't really wrap my head around what this means.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I can see how that's something one would have difficulty searching for!  The information you're looking for is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine

Comment: ...but the answer below is a much clearer entry to the concept than the wikipedia article or its introduction.

Answer (score 12):

An oracle is basically a magic black box that does something (e.g. query the entries of an array), usually in constant time. *How* the oracle does this is abstracted away from (and sometimes an oracle might even do something impossible like solve the halting problem). It's just a way of saying "presume we had these computational abilities, then ...".

Answer (score 0):

An oracle machine is an abstract machine which is assumed to solve a problem that might be undecidable or not yet solved.

For instance, "if we know how to solve problem A we can also solve problem B". Then we assume an "oracle" solving problem A even though we don't have a solution.

Comment: Oracle access is a more general concept.